# Get multiple solutions for 0/1-Knapsack MILP with lpSolveAPI

Tags: r, linear-programming, constraint-programming, lpsolve

**Reproducable Example:**

I described a simple [0/1-Knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem with [lpSolveAPI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/index.html) in [R](https://www.r-project.org), which should return 2 solutions:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

lp_model= make.lp(0, 3)
set.objfn(lp_model, c(100, 100, 200))
add.constraint(lp_model, c(100,100,200), "<=", 350)
lp.control(lp_model, sense= "max")
set.type(lp_model, 1:3, "binary")

lp_model
solve(lp_model)
get.variables(lp_model)
get.objective(lp_model)
get.constr.value((lp_model))
get.total.iter(lp_model)
get.solutioncount(lp_model)
```

**Problem:**

But `get.solutioncount(lp_model)` shows that there's just `1` solution found:

```
> lp_model
Model name: 
           C1   C2   C3         
Maximize  100  100  200         
R1        100  100  200  <=  350
Kind      Std  Std  Std         
Type      Int  Int  Int         
Upper       1    1    1         
Lower       0    0    0         
> solve(lp_model)
[1] 0
> get.variables(lp_model)
[1] 1 0 1
> get.objective(lp_model)
[1] 300
> get.constr.value((lp_model))
[1] 350
> get.total.iter(lp_model)
[1] 6
> get.solutioncount(lp_model)
[1] 1
```

I would expect that there are 2 solutions: `1 0 1` and `0 1 1`.

I tried to pass the `num.bin.solns` argument of [lpSolve](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html) with `solve(lp_model, num.bin.solns=2)`, but the number of solutions remained `1`.

**Question:**

How can I get the two correct solutions?
I prefer using [lpSolveAPI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/index.html) as the API is really nice.
If possible I'd like to avoid to use [lpSolve](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html) directly.

Comment: Kjell Konis, the author of lpSolveAPI wrote to me: The current version of lp_solve (the software underlying lpSolveAPI) does not support multiple solutions to milps. You can roll your own by adding constraints which is what the lpSolve package does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like that is broken. Here is a DIY approach for your specific model:

```
# first problem
rc<-solve(lp_model)
sols<-list()
obj0<-get.objective(lp_model)
# find more solutions
while(TRUE) {
   sol <- round(get.variables(lp_model))
   sols <- c(sols,list(sol))
   add.constraint(lp_model,2*sol-1,"<=", sum(sol)-1)
   rc<-solve(lp_model)
   if (rc!=0) break;
   if (get.objective(lp_model)<obj0-1e-6) break;
}
sols
```

The idea is to cut off the current integer solution by adding a constraint. Then resolve. Stop when no longer optimal or when the objective starts to deteriorate. [Here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2011/10/integer-cuts.html) is some math background.

You should see now:

```
> sols
[[1]]
[1] 1 0 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 1
```

**Update**

Below in the comments it was asked why coefficients of the cut have the form **2*sol-1**. Again have a look at [the derivation](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2011/10/integer-cuts.html). Here is a counter example:

```
           C1   C2        
Maximize    0   10        
R1          1    1  <=  10
Kind      Std  Std        
Type      Int  Int        
Upper       1    1        
Lower       0    0
```

With "my" cuts this will yield:

```
> sols
[[1]]
[1] 0 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1
```

while using the suggested "wrong" cuts will give just:

```
> sols
[[1]]
[1] 0 1
```

Comment: I do not understand the lhs of the new constraint: 2*sol-1. Can you elaborate?

Comment: We need to create a constraint with coefficients c[j] that are as follows: c[j]=-1 if sol[j]=0 and c[j]=+1 if sol[j]=1. That corresponds to c[j] = 2*sol[j]-1.

Comment: Why not just: c[j]=0 if sol[j]=0 and c[j]=+1 if sol[j]=1 ?

Comment: Would work for this data, but not in general. The correct cut has these -1 coefficients.

Comment: Added a counter example

Comment: Thx for adding the counter example.