# Minimum required number of rows in a boolean matrix, such that the resulting submatrix has at least one `1` in each column?

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, matrix, subset

## Background

Let's say, in a boolean matrix `m`, we have `1`s randomly distributed in each row, e.g.,

```
> set.seed(1)

> (m <- matrix(+(runif(30) > 0.6), 6))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    1
[6,]    1    0    1    0    0
```

## Questions

With the example above, I have two questions:

1. How to *efficiently* compute **the minimal number of rows** such that the resulting sub-matrix has at least one `1` in each column?
2. How to *efficiently* enumerate the rows of all those sub-matrices?

## My Attempt

The first approach comes to my mind is using `combn`, and a brute-force example of my attempts is

```
f <- function(m) {
    n <- nrow(m)
    for (k in 1:n) {
        u <- combn(n, k, \(...) list(
            flag = all(colSums(m[..., , drop = FALSE]) > 0),
            idx = c(...)
        ), simplify = FALSE)
        lst <- Filter(\(x) x$flag, u)
        if (length(lst) > 0) {
            return(
                list(
                    minReqNrOfRows = k,
                    allCombos = lapply(lst, `[[`, "idx")
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and we can see that we need at least `3` rows (for example, the sub-matrix `m[c(1,4,5),]` has at least one `1` in each column) and there are in total `6` such kind of row tuples

```
> f(m)
$minReqNrOfRows
[1] 3

$allCombos
$allCombos[[1]]
[1] 1 4 5

$allCombos[[2]]
[1] 1 5 6

$allCombos[[3]]
[1] 2 4 5

$allCombos[[4]]
[1] 2 5 6

$allCombos[[5]]
[1] 3 4 5

$allCombos[[6]]
[1] 3 5 6
```

## Any advanced algorithms to improve the performance

I have to admit that `combn` is computationally heavy when having huger number rows in a matrix before finding the minimal required number of rows.

I am thinking: Are there more advanced algorithms that can avoid going through all possible row combinations? Probably dynamical programming or backtracking, but I need some hints. Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: @AllanCameron I am looking for the least required number of rows

Comment: This appears to be the [set cover optimization problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291214/how-to-add-link-or-code-in-comment-area), which is known to be NP-hard

Comment: I can't run your function Thomas - it uses a variable called `n` that hasn't been defined.

Comment: duplicate of this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112439/how-to-cover-given-entries-in-a-matrix-with-minimum-number-of-rows-and-columns

Comment: @AllanCameron Sorry, my bad, I missed one line `n <- nrow(m)`, now fixed.

Comment: @jblood94 yes, it is a set cover problem, but I guess `combn` is rather clumsy so I am wondering if there is any possibility to improve the efficiency from the coding perspective, despite that it is NP hard.

Comment: @Mark aha, that's good finding! I will take a look at that. I was thinking about solving it in a graph, but no idea shaped yet :P

Comment: This kind of problem is typically tackled by finding a result then using the available time to find a better one. That way doesn't necessarily find the optimal solution though. If you're adamant that you want the optimal solution(s) then there could be a lot of computation involved but at first glance it looks parallelisable. For a large matrix, I could write an OpenCL c program to run on a GPU, but I don't know how to do it in R.

Comment: The set cover problem can be solved as an integer linear program. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244061/get-multiple-solutions-for-0-1-knapsack-milp-with-lpsolveapi) for a method to return all solutions.

Comment: @jblood94 aha, this seems interesting...I never considered about solving this problem using integer linear programming, but curious to take a look how the the integer cuts works.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be faster if we use `CVXR` to solve the minimal required number of rows, i.e., `k`, first, and then find out the desired output from all `k`-tuples, ***BUT***, it is proven that this approach is **much slower**!!!

```
library(CVXR)

f1 <- function(m) {
    n <- nrow(m)
    for (k in 1:n) {
        u <- combn(n, k, \(...) list(
            flag = all(colSums(m[..., , drop = FALSE]) > 0),
            idx = c(...)
        ), simplify = FALSE)
        lst <- Filter(\(x) x$flag, u)
        if (length(lst) > 0) {
            return(
                list(
                    minReqNrOfRows = k,
                    allCombos = lapply(lst, `[[`, "idx")
                )
            )
        }
    }
}


f2 <- function(m) {
    n <- nrow(m)
    # use igraph to solve the minimal required nubmer of rows
    x <- Variable(1, n, boolean = TRUE)
    obj <- Minimize(sum_entries(x))
    constr <- list(sum_entries(x %*% m, axis = 2) >= 1)
    prob <- Problem(obj, constr)
    res <- solve(prob)
    k <- round(res$value)

    # filter the results from all k-tupbles
    u <- combn(n, k, \(...) list(
        flag = all(colSums(m[..., , drop = FALSE]) > 0),
        idx = c(...)
    ), simplify = FALSE)
    list(
        minReqNrOfRows = k,
        allCombos = lapply(Filter(\(x) x$flag, u), `[[`, "idx")
    )
}
```

## Benchmarking

```
microbenchmark(
    f1 = f1(m),
    f2 = f2(m),
    check = "equal"
)
```

shows

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval
   f1   236.9   270.10   340.195   289.70   377.9    806.2   100
   f2 58399.4 66965.85 81720.124 73988.95 88971.2 203266.3   100
```